# How to calculate average concurrently in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I defined two correct ways of calculating averages in python.

```
def avg_regular(values):
    total = 0
    for value in values:
        total += value
    return total/len(values)

def avg_concurrent(values):
    mean = 0
    num_of_values = len(values)
    for value in values:
        #calculate a small portion of the average for each num and add to the total
        mean += value/num_of_values  
    return mean
```

The first function is the regular way of calculating averages, but I wrote the second one because each run of the loop doesn't depend on previous runs. So theoretically the average can be computed in parallel.

However, the "parallel" one (without running in parallel) takes about 30% more time than the regular one.

Are my assumptions correct and worth the speed loss? 
if yes how can I make the second function run the second one parrallely?

if not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with asynchronous? In python asyncio does async IO, but this doesn't really help you. Do you want to speed up your calculations? Look into numpy. If you want to run on multiple cores look into multiprocessing (python threads can't run python code concurrently). Your second version does more work (each time a division and an addition) so I don't think it's very surprising that it needs more time.

Comment: @syntonym Sorry, I mean in parallel not async as so kinda like running in multiple threads. How would I use multiprocess for this?

Comment: Ofc the second one is slower. Much more divisions!

Comment: Are you after speed or are you only trying to understand multiprocessing/calculating things in parallel?

Comment: @syntonym I'm trying to understand, but isn't the benefit of multiprocessing a speed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you implemented is basically the difference between `(a1+a2+ ... + an) / n` and `(a1/n + a2/n + ... + an/n)`. The result is the same, but in the second version there are more operations (namely (n-1) more divisions) which slows the calculation down. You claimed that in the second version each loop run is independent of the others. In the first loop we need the following information to finish one loop run: `total` before the run and the current `value`. In the second version we need the following information to finish one loop run: `mean` before the run, the current `value` and `num_of_values`. As you see in the second version we even depend on more values!

But how could we divide the work between cores (which is the goal of multiprocessing)? We could just give one core the first half of the values and the second the second half, i.e. `((a1+a2+ ... + a(n//2)) + ( a(n//2 +1) + ... + a(n)) / n)`. Yes, the work of dividing by n is not splitted between the cores, but it's a single instruction so we don't really care. Also we need to add the left total and the right total, which we can't split, but again it's only a single operation.

So the code we want to run:

```
def my_sum(values):
    total = 0
    for value in values:
        total += value
    return total
```

There's still a problem with python - normally one could use threads to do the computations, because each thread will use one core. But in that case one has to take care that your program does not run into race conditions, and the python interpreter itself also needs to take care of that. CPython decided it's not worth it and basically only runs in one thread at a time. A basic solution is to use multiple processes via multiprocessing.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(5) as p:
        results = p.map(my_sum, [long_list[0:len(long_list)//2], long_list[len(long_list)//2:]))

    print(sum(results) / len(long_list)) # add subresults and divide by n
```

But of course multiple processes do not come for free. You need to fork, copy stuff, etc. so you will not gain a speedup of 2 as one could expect. Also the biggest slowdown is actually using python itself, it's not really optimized for fast numerical computations. There are various ways around that, but using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is probably the simplest. Just use:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.mean(long_list))
```

Which is probably much faster than the python version. I don't think numpy uses multiprocessing internal, so one could gain a boost by using multiple processes and a fast implementation (numpy or something other written in C) but normally numpy is fast enough.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you're right that Numpy doesn't typically use multiprocessing.  I _think_ however, that it does try to use vector/SIMD instructions where possible, which I believe is part of where the speed improvement comes from.

Comment: @Jarak It looks like numpy does some of its computational stuff via BLAS, so (when using an optimized version) it should use vector, SIMD, instruction level parallelism etc. Additionally one can compile BLAS with multithreading, but I'm not sure if a sum does use it. Generally python is relatively slow, because it needs to do lots of stuff (mostly creating python objects), and simply using something like [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) or [cython](http://cython.org/) should give a massive speedup